# Make a php routine check every 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this code on the header of my site:

```
<?php if(($Variable1 > 0) && (isset($_SESSION["role"]) && ($_SESSION["role"]==12 || $_SESSION["role"]==13))){ ?>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-block"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle">
            </i> Number Left: <?php echo $NumberLeft; ?></button>
            <?php } ?>
```

I want this code to run every 30 seconds.

I can't make a page refresh every 30 seconds because I would lose the data that is not saved until then in that page. So I need to refresh only the specific banner.
I found by searching I could refresh the header

```
(header('Refresh: 10; URL=http://yoursite.com/page.php');
```

but it's refreshing the whole page, which I do not want. Also, I would like this header-refresh to happen on all pages on the site since this header is common.

Comment: What do you mean by "running on the header" and "refreshing the header"? Keep in mind that your PHP code is executed by the server when receiving a request. If you want to update the page on the client side, you probably want to use JavaScript instead.

Comment: I'm not experienced with Javascript. Can i read from inside JavaScript the variables created by php ? (ie $Variable1, echo $NumberLeft) ?

Comment: JavaScript will only have access to the rendered HTML page, so it really depends on what you're trying to achieve exactly. I suggest you to edit your post and describe the root problem in details.

Comment: By the way, the `header()` function in PHP is for defining the **HTTP response**'s headers. It has nothing to do with the actual page header.